# Qt translate function call error

Tags: qt4, pyqt4

In my application sometimes there's error like this:

```
    msg = QtGui.qApp.translate("@default", error_msg)
TypeError: function takes exactly 5 arguments (1 given)
```

The strange is, that most of the time it works, error_msg is ALWAYS non empty string, so function really gets 2 arguments.

This code is placed in class inherited from QThread, new thread is correctly started and emit signal that execute slot. And slot's code failed with error above.

I can't put here my code, because it's too complex and I can't reproduce the bug in smaller example. When I played around, the worst that can happen is empty string as a result, never error like this. Even is QApplication is not initialized.

Because of this, I'm not sure if it's Qt4 or PyQt4 issue.

Any idea?

Thanks,
Michal

**Edit:** I got exactly same message when using

```
self.tr(error_msg)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colleague of mine already solved it. It happens when error_msg contains non ascii characters.

Solution (codec is Latin1 by default):

```
QtCore.QTextCodec.setCodecForTr(QtCore.QTextCodec.codecForName('utf-8'))
```